# Info about Kabbalah text translators E. Collé and H. Collé

Tags: translation, mysticism-kabbalah

I want to read a good English translation of Etz Chaim by Chaim Vital.  I found [this one](https://www.amazon.ca/Tree-Life-Palace-Kadmon-English-Hebrew/dp/1512065935/) online by E. Collé and H. Collé.  It appears to be scholarly,  but I can't find amy information online about the two translators themselves. I see there are many other kabbalistic texts translated by one or both of them so it would be good to understand what sort of translators they are.

In addition to the question of the general accuracy and quality of the translation,  I'd like to know what is their hermeneutic slant:   academic, spiritual,  Orthodox, etc?

I'm also very curious as to why there is no info available.  Are they intentionally anonymous?

Comment: From [an Amazon customer review](https://www.amazon.com/review/R915BA61XKQLH/ref=cm_cr_srp_d_rdp_perm?ie=UTF8&ASIN=1512065935): "_This book is written by the same authors as 'The Creation of the Universe according to the Bible, Kabbalah, Ancient Egyptians, Gnostics, and Hermetic Texts'. You may or may not want to learn this very holy text from authors who draw on non-Jewish sources in their discussions of creation._"

Comment: Anyone who translates advanced Kabbalistic works into English or another language is definitely not working in the Orthodox framework. There is an understanding that these are not books that one can just pick up and read without a thorough background in more basic Judaism.

Comment: Even those who can read this in the original Hebrew need a teacher well-versed in sod HaTorah to learn Eitz Chaim with. If you would like to explore some of these concepts on your own, pick up a copy of the Ramchal's 138 Gates of Wisdom.